# How can I get or fetch the status code login in into another website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP . NET MVC 5 application and I want to create a Login form for it. In the company where I work, there is already a CRM system that we must use to log in every day. I want that my application use those same credentials, so what I'm trying to do is to create a view where the user most introduce their Username and Password. After hitting click on the submit button, I want that the application checks if those credentials are valid on the CRM server (something like a POST request), and in case that this is succesfully, enter the application.

Right now I'm trying to run some tests, but I have no results.

How can I achieve this connection from begining to start (from view, to model, to controler to view again)?

I've tried some POST requests, but I'm not succesful

Get a true or false statement to know if the connection and credentials were correct

Comment: What have you done?show your code please

Comment: What’s the CRM system being used? Is it custom built or a commercial/open source solution?